# how to fill the colours in this music staff imported from another file

Tags: inkscape

I am trying to see if I can get a couple of things happening here. Can I change the background colour of movie maker because whenever I convert my svg to png files, I realised that some pictures can't be seen because of the black background colour in movie maker as shown below:

[image: how to change colour]

It looks great here and on inkscape but just doesn't look clear in movie maker...

Comment: Why don't you add a background to your SVG then? Besides, your image shows a white background, so I don't understand the question.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion here but there is a white background here but after converting it inito png files and then using it in movie maker, it is black

Comment: I also think that the default background color in movie maker is black

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just add a rectangle, move it to the bottom, then give it the color you want it to have.

SVGs created in Inkscape have a transparent background.

Comment: It used to work well but sometimes, the fill doesn't work

Comment: I dragged the picture to the bottom but can't seem to change the color

Comment: is this a svg problem? I got the svg pictures from wikipedia

Comment: @musician888 if it doesn't work why did you mark this answer as accepted? I'm confused. Have you seen the [tour]?

Comment: If filling a rectangle with the color you want 'doesn't work', please open another question for it. Another option would be to go through any one of the introductory tutorials that are available in Inkscape and on the web.